# Why is my alignment so bad?

Tags: align

I want to align `0 1 2 3` with `s p d f`

and I wrote this:

```
\begin{align*}
l = &0,\ &1,\ &2,\ &3,\ \cdots,\ n-1 \\
    &s,\ &p,\ &d,\ &f,\ \cdots
\end{align*}
```

But it turns out to be:
[image: 0123spdf]

How to align them correctly?

Comment: Unrelated, don't use `\cdots` here, this is dots with commas and thus belongs in the base line, aka use `\dots` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `alignedat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{alignedat}{5}
l&={} & 0, && \ 1, && \ 2, && \ 3, & \ \cdots,\ n-1 \\
 &    & s, && \ p, && \ d, && \ f, & \ \cdots
\end{alignedat}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

& alignment: rlrlrl

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        l ={}&0,\ &&1,\ &&2,\ &&3,\ \cdots,\ n-1 \\
        &s,\ &&p,\ &&d,\ &&f,\ \cdots
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one `&` is enough, but I still don't know the principle of `&` alignment:

```
\begin{align*}
l=\ &0,\ 1,\ 2,\ 3,\ \cdots,\ n-1 \\
    &s,\ p,\ d,\ f,\ \cdots
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: All `align`-like environments have the same pattern: `right align & left align & right align & left align` etc. See the following example: `\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
     right\;align\ &\ left\;align  & right\;align\ &\ left\;align \\
            right\ &\ left        &         right\ &\ left       \\
\end{align*}
\end{document}`

Comment: there is no alignment here, just accidental almost alignment as s p d f are not too different from 0 1 2 3 in width.